# Location of Including PHP File Affects Global Variable Scope

Tags: php, xampp, global

It appears that the location of my including file affects global variables inside of the included file. It's complicated. See below:

---

`/config.php`

```
<?php
    $domain = 'localhost';
    $database = 'db';
?>
```

---

`/functions.php`

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");

    function getDatabase() {
        global $database;

        return $database;
    }
?>
```

---

`/endpoint.php`

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/functions.php");

    print(getDatabase());
?>
```

---

`/api/endpoint.php`

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/functions.php");

    print(getDatabase());
?>
```

---

When I navigate to `/endpoint.php`, `db` is printed out. When I navigate to `/api/endpoint.php`, nothing prints. Can somebody please explain this behavior?

BTW: I am using XAMPP 5.5.19 and PHP 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in the second case, `functions.php` is looking to include config.php from within the current path which is `/api/`.

Also, why the `global $database` declaration if you are going to be calling `getDatabase()` anyway?

Comment: It's more complicated in my actual code, but I was able to simplify it to this.

Comment: Yep that worked. So why wasn't require_once failing in functions.php if it couldn't find config.php?

Comment: @MageWind Do you have a `config.php` file in the `/api` directory?

Comment: No I do not (filler text)